# Error writing regression results in data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am performing a series of annual cross-sectional regressions in R importing data from an excel workbook in which each sheet corresponds to a year, these go from 1995 to 2018. I face two problems, the first one is that I don't understand how I can add to the data frame the list of coefficients with their p-values. The second problem is that when I incorporate the bp and bg tests of each model inside the loop it throws the following error:

```
Error in y - z$residuals : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

The head(datos) is:

[image]

The dataset is available here https://wormhole.app/opeBQ#NVBkLHzguFPUVY0N4hbErg

The script is as follows:

```
 library(lmtest)
    library(olsrr)
    library(tseries)
    library(readxl)
    library(openxlsx) 
    library(dplyr)
    
    años <- 1995:2018 
    
    resultados <- list()
    
    for (año in años) {
      # Define el nombre del archivo Excel (puedes modificarlo según tus necesidades)
      archivo_excel <- "C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/Bases/base_Regresiones.xlsx"
      
      # Importa los datos desde la hoja correspondiente al año
      datos <- read_excel(archivo_excel, sheet = as.character(año))
    
      # Realiza la regresión con tus datos. Por ejemplo, aquí se asume que tienes dos columnas: 'variable_independiente' y 'variable_dependiente'.
      modelo <- lm(y ~ ., data = datos)
      
      # Calcula los estadísticos requeridos
      r_squared <- summary(modelo)$r.squared
      f_statistic <- summary(modelo)$fstatistic[1]
      ssr <- deviance(modelo)
      jb_test <- jarque.bera.test(residuals(modelo))
      bg_test <- bgtest(modelo)
      bp_test <- bptest(modelo)
      
      # Almacena los resultados en la lista, incluyendo el R-squared y el estadístico F
      resultados[[as.character(año)]] <- list(
        Año = año,
        R_squared = r_squared,
        F_statistic = f_statistic,
        u_squad = ssr,
        JBtest = jb_test$p.value,
        bgtest = bg_test$p.value,
        bptest = bp_test$p.value
      )
    }
    
    # Crear un DataFrame a partir de la lista de resultados
    resultados_df <- do.call(rbind, resultados)
```

I got this results

```
     Año  R_squared F_statistic u_squad  JBtest   
1995 1995 0.9480865 148.5375    10.46748 0.4176042
1996 1996 0.9485575 149.972     10.31898 0.2332913
1997 1997 0.9462563 142.0284    10.8743  0.3334412
1998 1998 0.9464819 143.84      10.8509  0.5535448
1999 1999 0.9475053 145.5997    10.57655 0.4754198
2000 2000 0.9472141 144.7519    10.81674 0.3440291
2001 2001 0.9504769 156.0998    10.27286 0.8708391
2002 2002 0.9494986 151.6648    10.43004 0.8408953
2003 2003 0.9502323 155.2925    10.36924 0.6420716
2004 2004 0.9501257 154.9432    10.38435 0.8029328
2005 2005 0.9498327 153.991     10.4385  0.2381718
2006 2006 0.9518624 160.8269    10.04476 0.3467262
2007 2007 0.9513862 159.1718    10.17184 0.3430534
2008 2008 0.9468287 144.8315    10.96748 0.4548003
2009 2009 0.9525406 163.2413    9.350981 0.5795036
2010 2010 0.948046  148.4155    10.10924 0.6508358
2011 2011 0.9510188 157.9168    9.487844 0.5200191
2012 2012 0.948731  150.507     9.751045 0.5669693
2013 2013 0.9453135 140.5932    10.37591 0.4488269
2014 2014 0.9465016 143.8963    10.07656 0.4465016
2015 2015 0.9469356 145.1395    10.06823 0.2957086
2016 2016 0.9479821 148.223     9.874893 0.2328414
2017 2017 0.9452753 140.4895    10.42455 0.1856073
2018 2018 0.9451515 140.154     10.45936 0.2261362
```

I expect to get something like the following:

[image]

Comment: To help understanding input data, could you write the output of `head(datos)` or even better, write the output of `dput(datos)` to reproduce your example

Comment: Where exactly does the error occur?

Comment: The error occurs when running loop.  Specifically in the lines where the following are located bg_test <- bgtest(modelo) bp_test <- bptest(modelo)

Comment: Looking at the help pages for those two functions, their first argument is supposed to be a formula, not data. The internal code does attempt to accommodate this and conform it to something it knows how to use, in my testing just now that logic is not useful for an object of class `lm`. (Mainly, I did the example in the bottom of `?bptest` but fed it `lm(y1~x)` instead of `y1~x`, and it complained about `partial match of 'x' to 'xlevels'`, which is a clear marker that it does not know how to work with `"lm"` objects correctly.) Try `bgtest(y ~ ., data = datos)` (and similarly for `bptest`).

Comment: We don't have your data so this is not reproducible. The fact that you get the same error despite fixing the mistake of calling `bgtest(.)` on an LM-object is a huge marker that something else in your data or your code is clearly wrong, I don't think it's specifically within `lmtest::` functions. I'll keep my answer up for now, at a minimum as a warning against trusting anything that complains about "partial match".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bottom line**: I think you need to be using the formula interface with `bptest` and `bgtest` as well. Namely, try

```r
bg_test <- lmtest::bgtest(y ~ ., data = datos)
bp_test <- lmtest::bptest(y ~ ., data = datos)
```

I'm not familiar enough with the tests (nor with your data) to know exactly, but I believe that `bgtest` does not know what to do with an object of class `"lm"`. A demonstration of this, using the sample data from `?bptest` as a starting point:

```r
set.seed(42)
     x <- rep(c(-1,1), 50)
     ## generate heteroskedastic and homoskedastic disturbances
     err1 <- rnorm(100, sd=rep(c(1,2), 50))
     err2 <- rnorm(100)
     ## generate a linear relationship
     y1 <- 1 + x + err1
     y2 <- 1 + x + err2
lmtest::bptest(y1 ~ x)
#   studentized Breusch-Pagan test
# data:  y1 ~ x
# BP = 9.012, df = 1, p-value = 0.002682
lm(y1 ~ x)
# Call:
# lm(formula = y1 ~ x)
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)            x  
#       1.047        1.010  
lmtest::bptest(lm(y1 ~ x))
# Warning in formula$x : partial match of 'x' to 'xlevels'
#   studentized Breusch-Pagan test
# data:  lm(y1 ~ x)
# BP = 9.012, df = 1, p-value = 0.002682
```

The fact that it conducted the test without *failing* with an `Error:` does not mean it is correct. The warning about `partial match` says to me that it tried internally to convert the `"lm"` object into something it knows how to deal with. When there's a "partial match" warning, this means that our `x` variable here is actually being interpreted as `xlevels=` in something, which is certainly not what we think should be happening.

Comment: How can I put the coefficients and their p-values in results_df?

Comment: If you want the coefficients from one model to add to the results of another model/test, then run the `lm(..)`, extract its coefficients, then combine with the results. What does that have to do with the error/question?

Comment: I asked both questions in the post

Comment: Okay, I was answering the title-question. For your first ... coefficients are just a few numbers, you want to add them to columns and/or rows of your original data? How is that supposed to look? Why do you think you need to add coefficients to the data frame?

Comment: Could each coefficient be written in separate columns where the rows correspond to a year? In the last image of the post there is an example.

Comment: I don't understand how you expect to come up with `X1:X6` when your model output has one row per year. Have you tried using `coef(modelo)` to get your coefficients? I can't reproduce any of this, so it is rather difficult to walk you through how to code in R over a chat interface like this. If this is for a class, perhaps this is a good time to chat with the TA, teacher, or professor?

Comment: Here I put the question in a more specific way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77398782/write-lm-results-to-a-table