# Write lm results to a table

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am performing a series of annual cross-sectional regressions in R importing data from an excel workbook in which each sheet corresponds to a year, these go from 1995 to 2018. I don't understand how I can add to the `resultados_df`  the list of coefficients with their p-values.

The script is as follows:

```
library(lmtest)
library(olsrr)
library(tseries)
library(readxl)
library(openxlsx) 
library(dplyr)

años <- 1995:2018 

resultados <- list()

for (año in años) {
  # Define el nombre del archivo Excel (puedes modificarlo según tus necesidades)
  archivo_excel <- "C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/Bases/base_Regresiones.xlsx"
  
  # Importa los datos desde la hoja correspondiente al año
  datos <- read_excel(archivo_excel, sheet = as.character(año))

  # Realiza la regresión con tus datos. Por ejemplo, aquí se asume que tienes dos columnas: 'variable_independiente' y 'variable_dependiente'.
  modelo <- lm(y ~ ., data = datos)
  
  # Calcula los estadísticos requeridos
  r_squared <- summary(modelo)$r.squared
  f_statistic <- summary(modelo)$fstatistic[1]
  ssr <- deviance(modelo)
  pvalues <- summary(modelo)$coefficients[, "Pr(>|t|)"]
  jb_test <- jarque.bera.test(residuals(modelo))
  bg_test <- bgtest(modelo)
  
  # Almacena los resultados en la lista, incluyendo el R-squared y el estadístico F
  resultados[[as.character(año)]] <- list(
    Año = año,
    R_squared = r_squared,
    F_statistic = f_statistic,
    u_squad = ssr,
    Coeficientes = coef(modelo),
    Pvalues = pvalues,
    JBtest = jb_test$p.value,
    BGtest = bg_test$p.value,
    BPtest = bp_test$p.value
  )
}

# Crear un DataFrame a partir de la lista de resultados
resultados_df <- do.call(rbind, resultados)
```

I got these results

```
 Año  R_squared F_statistic u_squad  JBtest   
1995 0.9480865 148.5375    10.46748 0.4176042
1996 0.9485575 149.972     10.31898 0.2332913
1997 0.9462563 142.0284    10.8743  0.3334412
1998 0.9464819 143.84      10.8509  0.5535448
1999 0.9475053 145.5997    10.57655 0.4754198
2000 0.9472141 144.7519    10.81674 0.3440291
2001 0.9504769 156.0998    10.27286 0.8708391
2002 0.9494986 151.6648    10.43004 0.8408953
2003 0.9502323 155.2925    10.36924 0.6420716
2004 0.9501257 154.9432    10.38435 0.8029328
2005 0.9498327 153.991     10.4385  0.2381718
2006 0.9518624 160.8269    10.04476 0.3467262
2007 0.9513862 159.1718    10.17184 0.3430534
2008 0.9468287 144.8315    10.96748 0.4548003
2009 0.9525406 163.2413    9.350981 0.5795036
2010 0.948046  148.4155    10.10924 0.6508358
2011 0.9510188 157.9168    9.487844 0.5200191
2012 0.948731  150.507     9.751045 0.5669693
2013 0.9453135 140.5932    10.37591 0.4488269
2014 0.9465016 143.8963    10.07656 0.4465016
2015 0.9469356 145.1395    10.06823 0.2957086
2016 0.9479821 148.223     9.874893 0.2328414
2017 0.9452753 140.4895    10.42455 0.1856073
2018 0.9451515 140.154     10.45936 0.2261362
```

And I hope to get the following

```
 Año  R_squared F_statistic u_squad  JBtest   constant x1       x2...    x2018 pvalue_x1... pvalue_x2018
1995 0.9480865 148.5375    10.46748 0.4176042 0.344558 0.245688 0.242411        0.03
1996 0.9485575 149.972     10.31898 0.2332913 0.545682 0.833226 0.643456        0.02
1997 0.9462563 142.0284    10.8743  0.3334412 0.788953 0.412100 0.142731        0.11
1998 0.9464819 143.84      10.8509  0.5535448
1999 0.9475053 145.5997    10.57655 0.4754198
2000 0.9472141 144.7519    10.81674 0.3440291
2001 0.9504769 156.0998    10.27286 0.8708391
2002 0.9494986 151.6648    10.43004 0.8408953
2003 0.9502323 155.2925    10.36924 0.6420716
2004 0.9501257 154.9432    10.38435 0.8029328
2005 0.9498327 153.991     10.4385  0.2381718
2006 0.9518624 160.8269    10.04476 0.3467262
2007 0.9513862 159.1718    10.17184 0.3430534
2008 0.9468287 144.8315    10.96748 0.4548003
2009 0.9525406 163.2413    9.350981 0.5795036
2010 0.948046  148.4155    10.10924 0.6508358
2011 0.9510188 157.9168    9.487844 0.5200191
2012 0.948731  150.507     9.751045 0.5669693
2013 0.9453135 140.5932    10.37591 0.4488269
2014 0.9465016 143.8963    10.07656 0.4465016
2015 0.9469356 145.1395    10.06823 0.2957086
2016 0.9479821 148.223     9.874893 0.2328414
2017 0.9452753 140.4895    10.42455 0.1856073
2018 0.9451515 140.154     10.45936 0.2261362
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by writing a little "tidy" function that collects all the results.  In this case, the function `my_tidy()` takes a model as input and outputs a data frame with all the stuff you want in a single row.  Then you can use `bind_rows()` to put everything together.  Here's an example with the `mtcars` data.

```r
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl, levels=c(4,6,8), 
                     labels=c("4 cyl", "6 cyl", "8 cyl"))

my_tidy <- function(model, ...){
  s <- summary(model)
  pvalues <- s$coefficients[,4]
  jb_test <- DescTools::JarqueBeraTest(residuals(model))
  bg_test <- lmtest::bgtest(model)
  bp_test <- lmtest::bptest(model)
  coefs <- do.call(data.frame, as.list(coef(model)))
  pvals <- do.call(data.frame, as.list(pvalues))
  names(pvals) <- paste0("p.", names(pvals))
  bind_cols(
    tibble::tibble(
      R_squared = s$r.squared,
      F_statistic = s$fstatistic[1],
      u_squad = deviance(model),
      JBtest = jb_test$p.value,
      BGtest = bg_test$p.value, 
      BPtest = bp_test$p.value), 
    coefs, 
    pvals)
}
```

```r
res <- list()
for(x in levels(mtcars$cyl)){
  model <- lm(qsec ~ hp + wt + drat + disp, 
              data = filter(mtcars, cyl == x))
  res[[x]] <- my_tidy(model)
}

bind_rows(res, .id="cyl")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 17
#>   cyl   R_squared F_statistic u_squad JBtest  BGtest BPtest X.Intercept.
#>   <chr>     <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 4 cyl     0.596        2.22  11.4    0.637 0.125    0.157         18.5
#> 2 6 cyl     0.989       43.1    0.200  0.691 0.00886  0.152         12.0
#> 3 8 cyl     0.930       30.0    1.30   0.213 0.518    0.311         19.3
#> # ℹ 9 more variables: hp <dbl>, wt <dbl>, drat <dbl>, disp <dbl>,
#> #   p.X.Intercept. <dbl>, p.hp <dbl>, p.wt <dbl>, p.drat <dbl>, p.disp <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>